# Sum 1 ~ N, without using multiplication, division, if, while, for, switch and ternary expression

Tags: c++, templates

Today, I try to solve one weird (kind of) question with my friend, .

> Try to get the sum of `1 + 2 + ··· + n`, without using multiplication and division, for, while, if, else, switch, case, ternary expression and other keywords.

Here are our solutions

- **constructor**

  ```
  class Sum
  {
  public:
      Sum() { ++num; sum += num; }
      static void Init() { num = 0; sum = 0; }
      static unsigned int SumValue() { return sum; }
  private:
      static unsigned int num;
      static unsigned int sum;
  };
  unsigned int Sum::num = 0;
  unsigned int Sum::sum = 0;

  unsigned int get_sum(unsigned int n)
  {
      Sum::Init();

      Sum * tmp = new Sum[n];
      delete[] tmp;

      return Sum::SumValue();
  }
  ```
- **recursive**

  ```
  class Ba
  {
  public:
      virtual unsigned int sum(unsigned int n)
      {
           return 0;
      }
  };

  Ba* sumArray[2];

  class D : public Ba
  {
  public:
       virtual unsigned int sum(unsigned int n)
       {
            return sumArray[!!n]->sum(n - 1) + n;
       }
  };

  unsigned int get_sum2(unsigned int n)
  {
      Ba b;
      D d;
      sumArray[0] = &b;
      sumArray[1] = &d;

      return sumArray[1]->sum(n);
  }
  ```

We think maybe this question could be solved var `template`? However, we failed to figure it out. Is it possible to do that with `template`?

BTW, we try to find the same question in this site, but we failed. Sorry to this duplicated question if it is.

Comment: You're using `class`, `public`, `virtual`, `unsigned`, `int`, `return`. All of those are keywords. (The question is stupid and unanswerable. I'm not blaming you for it.)

Answer (score 3):

with a minimum of keywords, using short circuit evaluation

```
unsigned sum(unsigned n) {
    unsigned i=0;
    n && (i=n+sum(n-1));
    return i;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I suspect this question will be closed soon, but it sounds like what you're after is the following: a pretty standard introduction to the idea of compile-time recursion, used heavily in template metaprogramming.

```
template <int I>
struct sum {
    static constexpr int value = I + sum<I-1>::value;
};

template <>
struct sum<0> {
    static constexpr int value = 0;
};


int main() {
    std::cout << sum<5>::value << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We have that the sum of the first N numbers is `S = N(N+1)/2 = (N^2 + N)/2`. Therefore,

```
int main()
{
    int N = 10;
    int sum = (N*N + N) >> 1;
}
```

Comment: "without multiplication"

Comment: @sp2danny Good catch, I missed that one. Btw, just call pow.

Answer (score 1):

What about using algorithms?

**std::iota**

```
template< class ForwardIterator, class T >
void iota( ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last, T value );
```

> Fills the range [first, last) with sequentially increasing values,
>   starting with value and repetitively evaluating ++value.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota

**std::accumulate**

```
template< class InputIt, class T >
T accumulate( InputIt first, InputIt last, T init );
```

> Computes the sum of the given value init and the elements in the range
>   [first, last).

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate

**Example:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int sum(const int n) {
    std::vector<int> v(n);

    std::iota(begin(v), end(v), 1);
    return std::accumulate(begin(v), end(v), 0);
}

int main() {
    const int n = 12;
    std::cout << "Sum: " << sum(n) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

https://ideone.com/ajOhWM

Answer (score 0):

Recursion is probably the expected solution, but by no means as complex as you have made it.

```
unsigned num( unsigned n ){ return n ; }
unsigned sum1toN( unsigned n ) ;
unsigned (*function[])() = { sum1toN, num } ;

unsigned sum1toN( unsigned n )
{
    return n + (function[n==1])( n - 1 ) ;
}
```

Comment: Not just `int sum1toN(int n) { return n == 0 ? 0 : n + sum1toN(n - 1) }`? EDIT: Ah, no ternary, never mind :-)

Comment: @TristanBrindle : *"without using [...]  ternary expression"*